# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined when iterating over item list

Tags: javascript, webpack

In trying to log the content of item.list to the console; I get the following error above

```
const navitems = [];

const dropDownFactory = (name, list) => ({ name, list });

const firstDropdownObject = dropDownFactory('sara', ["one", "two", "three"]);
    
navitems.push(firstDropdownObject);

navitems.forEach((item) => {
    const navItemDiv = document.createElement('div');
    const navItem = document.createElement('a');
    navItem.setAttribute('href', '#');
    navItem.innerHTML = item.name;
    navItemDiv.appendChild(navItem);
    navBar.appendChild(navItemDiv);

    item.list.forEach((i) => {
        console.log(i);
    });
})
```

The value of item.list is the array ["one", "two", "three"], which is the second argument of the dropdown object that was generated using the dropdown factory.

When I logged item.list to the console, it's type showed up as array meaning it's iterable but when I use forEach on it, it comes as undefined. Can someone please help point out why it sees item as undefined?

Comment: `navitems` is an array of strings.  Strings do not have a `list` property

Comment: It's not clear what you're expecting `dropDownFactory` to do in relation to this code, since you assign the result to `one`, but never use `one` again in the code shown here.

Comment: can you show us the value of the ``item.list`` that "showed up" as an array?

Comment: dropDownFactory just generates a drop-down object. The first parameter is the header and the second is the array of items that will be attached to the header.

Comment: The value of item.list is the array ["one", "two", "three"]